# HTML element aligned to the right to fill left space to another dynamic element

Tags: css, html

OK guys, here's my problem. I have a navigation bar on my website, which can be customized by the administrator of the site - he can add links to the navigation bar, so that list has dynamic width. At the right corner of the bar, I have a div element with a search box. These are the CSS properties of these two divs:

```css
.head_navigation
{
    float:left;
    height:51px;
    padding-top:7px;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    background:url("images/top_nav_bckg.gif") repeat-x bottom;
    text-align: center;
}

.head_navigation_right{
    float:right;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:7px;
    height:51px;
    background:url("images/top_nav_bckg_right.gif") repeat-x bottom;
    text-align:right;
}
```

I can't make the right div fill the blank space to its left side. Since the left div is dynamic, I can't set a fixed margin for the right one. I also tried:

```css
width: 100%;
```

and it puts the right div to the row below and fills the whole page. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Zx9gw/1/

From head_navigation_right remove the float property.

```
.head_navigation_right{
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:7px;
    height:51px;
    background:url("images/top_nav_bckg_right.gif") repeat-x bottom;
    text-align:right;
}​
```

Unfortunately I can't tell you why this is, I can just assume: float changes the display of an element, so that any *other* elements would take the rest of the space.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks a lot! At first my left div wasn't dynamic, and I had fixed widths, so float:right did the job. But now since I changed that, I didn't guess that float:right would be the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW This will look funny if `.head_navigation_right` happens to be higher than the left one. Still, very useful!

Comment: I guess you mean the red background which will appear below the left content. If so - this is actually what float:left does. It's like putting an image in a word document with word wrap set to rectangle. If this is not what you need, you might want to use a table or set width/height on the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Put both left and right div in a div container with the background you want.

for instance:

```
<div id="menuBar">
     <div class="head_navigation"></div>
     <div class="head_navigation_right"></div>
     <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

And then give menuBar the background you want... Hope i understood the question right.

**Edit - another solution**

make the container of .head_navigation and .head_navigation_right position:relative; and give a height, if it doesnt have one.
then apply this to your css:

```
.head_navigation
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
    height:51px;
    padding-top:7px;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    border:0;
    background:url("images/top_nav_bckg.gif") repeat-x bottom;
        text-align: center;
}

.head_navigation_right{

    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:2;
border:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-top:7px;
height:51px;
background:url("images/top_nav_bckg_right.gif") repeat-x bottom;
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: I think this could have worked as well. I already solved it with Slomo's suggestion though. Thanks anyway.